# Send values from asp page to SQL stored procedure and return value?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a scenario where essentially I need to cancel an order from an asp page, calling a SQL stored procedure, and then the stored procedure needs to send back generic responses to be displayed or used on the ASP page...but I don't know what statements I need on the asp side and sql side to make it work?

For example:

ASP:

```
Dim cmdSearch, prmFields
Set cmdCancel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set prmFields=cmdCancel.CreateParameter("@order_id",adNumeric,adParamInput,9, order_id) 
prmFields.Precision=9
cmdAdmin.Parameters.Append prmFields
Set prmFields=cmdAdmin.CreateParameter("@customer_id",adNumeric,adParamInput,5, customer_id)
prmFields.Precision=5
cmdAdmin.Parameters.Append prmFields
cmdCancel.CommandText = "sp_cancel_order"
```

Then the stored procedure will look something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_cancel_order]
    --order ID passed
    @order_id numeric(9,0),
    --customer id passed
    @customer_id numeric(5,0),
    @status char(1)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @status = 'A' --TEST VALUE

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF @order_id <> '' AND @order_id IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF @status = '' OR @status = 'A' OR @status = 'B'
        BEGIN
            --Insert cancellation record into cancel table
            EXEC sp_insert_cancel @order_id
                   --NEED TO SEND BACK STATIC (SUCCESS) MESSAGE TO ASP PAGE HERE
        END
    END
    ELSE
    --NEED TO SEND BACK STATIC (ERROR) MESSAGE TO ASP PAGE HERE
END
```

Comment: have you considered using a boolean/bit output parameter, that simply returns true if cancelled and false otherwise?

Comment: Is your plan to use an `OUTPUT` parameter in your stored procedure? Because you can use `adParamOutput` and return a numeric "error code" value.

Comment: Hi @Bond, it sounds like I'm looking for something like you're suggesting. How would the code look on each end?

Comment: I just added an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, using an output parameter in your stored procedure.

Modify your stored procedure to include an output param:

```
@order_id numeric(9,0),
@customer_id numeric(5,0),
@status char(1),
@message nvarchar(40) OUTPUT
```

And assign it the proper error/return message:

```
SET @message = 'Error: I got confused.'
```

In your VBScript code, add the param to your command object:

```
Set prmFields = cmdAdmin.CreateParameter("Message", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 40)
cmdAdmin.Parameters.Append prmFields
```

Later, after you execute your command, you can retrieve its output/return value:

```
cmdAdmin.Parameters("Message").Value
```

This is just an example of passing back a value (a string in this case) from a stored procedure. You could pass back a numeric error value instead, and lookup the error description as part of your ASP page, or pass back a simple boolean (true/false, pass/fail) value. Up to you.

Comment: It's worth noting that output parameters can only be accessed once all resultsets have been returned.